# Rest API not working on IE11, but working on Chrome and edge

Tags: rest, api, sharepoint-2013

I have a Rest API which is returning results in Chrome and Edge, but doesn't return any results in IE11, can someone please help?

```
  http://URL/SiteCollection/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('ListName')/items?$select=ID&$filter=((Item_x0020_Number eq '11000000018') and (AX_Customer_x0020_ID eq '31000001461') and (ParentID eq '154') and ((Request_x0020_Status eq 'X') or (Request_x0020_Status eq 'Y') or (Request_x0020_Status eq 'Z')))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

As we talked earlier, in IE browser, the space character not convert to escape charater %20, you can modify the Url manually and try to test again to see if it works.

Comment: I did this but it didnt work, moreover in debug mode, while I am trying to put this request, it actually doesn't move the spaces with %20% in OR AND braces, while in chrome it does.

Comment: Seems in IE browser, the space character not convert to escape charater %20, you can modify the Url manually and try to test again to see if it works.

Comment: Hi Moranis, I will modify the code snippet as talked and you could accept as answer so that this thread can be closed.